# Pandas cant open csv file :FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File xyz.csv does not exist:

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Catalogue.csv')
print(df)
```

I downloaded my earthquake csv file. And pandas dont see the file. I use VS Code and Python 3.8.3 I added csv file in the same py file where I write my code.
[image]

Even if I used the same code (csv was in the same folder where my code file was) in Jupyter Notebook folder the result were the same.
I guess if it is excel `pip instal xlrd` is written. I did `pip install python-csv` but couldnt achieve installing. Is it needed though? Or do I need to fixe the csv file (commas or spaces)?

total result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Fatma Elik/Documents/VS Code/BTK/CSVCSV.py", line 2, in <module>
    df=pd.read_csv('Catalogue.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\der(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File Catalogue.csv does not exist: 'Catalogue.csv'
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("c://Users//Fatma Elik//Documents//VS Code//BTK//Catalogue.csv")
print(df)
```

Comment: When I did that I got :` UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 8: invalid continuation byte`  I converted Excel file to CSV. Than I did `df=pd.read_csv("c://Users//Fatma Elik//Documents//VS Code//BTK//Catalogue.csv", error_bad_lines=False)` later `df=pd.read_csv("c://Users//Fatma Elik//Documents//VS Code//BTK//Catalogue.csv", sep='delimiter', header=None)`  both show the data differently. Also there are speciel characters (etc.ş,ö,ü)

Comment: You need to identify the separator in the file. Normally it is a comma, but it can be semicolon as well or other special characters.
To identify, open the file with a text editor.

Comment: You can post a snapshot of the file here. Then I can help you.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3iPv.png                         This is one of my files

Comment: Try df=pd.read_csv("c://Users//Fatma Elik//Documents//VS Code//BTK//Catalogue.csv", header=None, encoding = "utf-8")

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few scenarios that this situation might occur. Perhaps I can offer a few common suggestions for you to try.

### Case 1 - Location where you run Python

Your file path is correct with respect to the location of the .py file, but incorrect with respect to the location from which you call python.

For example, let's say CSVCSV.py is located in ~/script/, and Catalogue.csv is located in ~/script/.

If you run `python script/CSVCSV.py` from ~/ , you will get the FileNotFound error. However, if from ~/script/ you run `python CSVCSV.py`, it will work.

In your case specifically, are you perhaps running python from .../BTK or .../VS Code ? I might take a guess that you are running `python c:/Users/Fatma Elik/Documents/VS Code/BTK/CSVCSV.py`.

### Case 2 - Try using full directory path

Have you tried `df = pd.read_csv("C://Users//Fatma Elik//Documents//VS Code//BTK//Catalogue.csv")`  ?

Answer (score 0):

This situation usually occurs when you try to write a file in a particular directory, but the directory is not available. Let's say, you are trying to write records in data/hist/sign_seqs.csv but hist directory is not present.